# Laravel перенаправление на контроллер в посреднике

Tags: php, laravel

При попытке в посреднике проверить url и перенаправить пользователя на метод контроллера, Laravel пишет, что метод в контроллере не определен ("Action not defined"). Хотя метод при этом существует, но он нигде не указан в роутинге.

Правильно ли вообще в посредниках перенаправлять на методы контроллеров, или я что-то не то делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неправильно. Метод контроллера указываете в роутере вместе с посредником, а не в самом посреднике. Например:

```
    Route::get('/admin','admincontroller@index')->middleware('auth');
```

И не забудьте зарегистрировать новый посредник в ядре kernel